# Unable to restart Apache: What does this response mean?

Tags: command-line, apache2

This is my first time trying to use Apache and Ubuntu, and one of the steps I'm trying to follow is restarting apache with the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

It isn't working and the response I'm getting is:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl - xe" for details
```

What should I do now? Any guidance would be really helpful and majorly appreciated!

Comment: Uh, do what it says? Execute those commands.

Comment: @muru oh! I didn't know that those were commands - thanks :)